# PowerShell Regex filtering

Tags: regex, powershell

A little question for the regex experts. I have 3 different groups of charachters I would like to have separated, maybe you guys can help me out a bit.

```
$Dash = '-', '-*','*-','L-','-L' # always a dash sign with or without something else
$Blank = '', $null, ' ','*',' *', '* ', '   ' # no letter, no dash, but possible asterix
$Char = 'L', 'F','R*','*C',' C','C ' # always a letter that can be either L, F, C or R with or without asterix or space
```

I started like this, because I'm not a regex expert, but it doesn't work out so wel and becomes overcomplicated:

```
$array | foreach {
            if ($_ -match '-') {Write-Host "Dash : $_" -ForegroundColor Cyan}
            elseif (($_ -eq '') -or ($_ -eq $null) -or ($_ -eq ' ') -or ($_ -like ‘`* ’)) {Write-Host "Blank : $_" -ForegroundColor Yellow}
            else {Write-Host "Perm : $_" -ForegroundColor Magenta}

        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to describe with more details what kind of patterns you are after. Some examples about valid and invalid matches would be nice too.

Comment: The valid options are the ones defined in `$Dash`, `$Blank` and `$Char`. Everything else should fail the regexes. So in total 3 different regexes are needed to separate the results. I hope this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

always a dash sign with or without something else

```
-(?:\S*)|(?:\S*)-
```

no letter, no dash, but possible asterix

```
[^a-zA-Z-]*\*?
```

Always a letter that can be either L, F, C or R with or without asterix  or space

```
[LFCR][\* ]?|[\* ]?[LFCR]
```

Comment: Thank you Walid, just what I was looking for :) Is there also an option to have this regex `-(?:\S*)|(?:\S*)-` except `$null` and `white space(s)` to? So I can replace this `($_ -match '-(?:\S*)|(?:\S*)-') -or ($_ -eq $null) -or ($_ -eq ' ')`

Comment: I think I found it, going with this one:  `'-(?:\S*)|(?:\S*)-|\s|^$'`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Switch command (I always recommend this when there is more than a binary result from an If statement... in other words, if you ever need ElseIf, I would suggest using Switch).

```
Switch($array){
    {$_ -match "-"}{Write-Host "Dash : $_" -ForegroundColor Cyan}
    {[string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_) -or $_ -match "^\s*?\*+\s*?$"}{Write-Host "Blank : $_" -ForegroundColor Yellow}
    {$_ -match "(?:\s|\*)?[lfrc](?:\s|\*)?"}{Write-Host "Perm : $_" -ForegroundColor Magenta}
}
```

Comment: You are right, the `Switch` is a much better approach. Thank you for your help :)